# Angular 4 - Show and hide components

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have the next components in the same html file.

```html
<app-form></app-form>
<app-results [hidden]="isOn"></app-results>
<app-contact-primary [hidden]="!isOn"></<app-contact-primary>
<app-contact-second [hidden]="!isOn"></app-contact-second>
```

In component "app-form", I have two buttons:

```html
<button pButton label="Contact" (click)="">Contact</button>
<button pButton label="Results" (click)="">Results</button>
```

If I do click on button "Contact" must to show the component "app-contact-primary" and "app-contact-second" and to hide the "app-results" component.

But if I do click in button "Results" must to hide components "app-contact-primary" and "app-contact-second" and show "app-results" component.

How I could do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use hidden property or `*ngIf` directive :

```html
<app-form></app-form>
<app-results *ngIf="isOn"></app-results>
<app-contact-primary *ngIf="!isOn"></<app-contact-primary>
<app-contact-second *ngIf="!isOn"></app-contact-second>

<button pButton label="Contact" (click)="isOn= false">Contact</button>
<button pButton label="Results" (click)="isOn= true">Results</button>
```

Comment: Yes,  I tried it before but nothing happened maybe I have to pass "isOn" as parameter at component , from son to father and to father to son, the four components are inside the component  "app-main", this would be the component father.

Comment: Would this trigger the ngcycle events after condition gets satisfied?

Comment: Buy doing this we have to hookup our own cycle of navigation to the entire application the default back will not work. Is this okay to have the entire application follow this structure of showing and hiding components ?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the variable true and false

```html
<button pButton label="Contact" (click)="isOn = true">Contact</button>
<button pButton label="Results" (click)="isOn = false">Results</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using it

Typescript:

```typescript
public show: boolean = false;
public buttonName: any = true;

toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;
    if(this.show)
        this.buttonName = false;
    else
        this.buttonName = true;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div *ngIf="show">
<textarea #todoitem class="></textarea>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="addItem('status')">Add</button>
<button type="button" (click)="toggle()">Close</button>
<div *ngIf="buttonName">
<a (click)="toggle()"><i class="fa fa-plus text-white"></i></a>
</div>
```